# Where is the most appropriate place to ask a question about hosting providers?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to ask a question about developer's experiences with different Windows Dedicated Server hosting providers.  Assuming that my question is technology-specific, and worded as objectively as possible, Is this off-topic for SO?  Where is the most appropriate place to ask such a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowhere.

I'm saying this without definitive proof as I cannot locate it in a reasonable amount of time, but to the best of my recollection this type of "buying guide" question is not welcome anywhere.

**However** you could probably troll the chats for [Webmasters](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) and [Server Fault](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) and ask for advice there.  Unfortunately, while [Webmasters chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) would be a fine place to start, it seems a bit cobwebby in there.

Answer (score 5):

Questions tagged [hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting), [web-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting), and [looking-for-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-hosting) don't seem to be getting closed on Web Masters.  You might want to ask on [their site-specific Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/) just be be sure your questions will be on-topic there.